# Easier way to enter data from Excel for quiz app?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Trying to make a Quiz app. I have the following for each question.

````
<QF id="AB2590" topic="PT" category="CM" ni_exempt="no">
    <question>
        <text>Question goes here</text>
        <graphic></graphic>
        <prompt>Mark X correct answers</prompt>

    </question>
    <answers>
        <answer correct="yes">
            <text>Answer</text>
            <graphic></graphic>
        </answer>
        <answer correct="yes">
            <text>Answer</text>
            <graphic></graphic>
        </answer>
        <answer correct="yes">
            <text>Answer</text>
            <graphic></graphic>
        </answer>
        <answer correct="no">
            <text>Answer</text>
            <graphic></graphic>
        </answer>
    </answers>
    <explanation>
        <text>Add explanation</text>
        <voice id="AB2590-2"/>
    </explanation>
</QF>```
````

My colleague already sent an excel file full of questions

[List of questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9BnX.jpg)

Is there an easier way than manually typing in each question/answer? Bc thats gonna be ALOT of copy and pasting. Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with exporting from Excel app as CSV file and if necessary transform that CSV file with a script (written in Java/Python/bash whatever) into a format you can use?

Comment: You know, that Excels *.xlsm file is an XML file. I would first open this Ecel file in an XML editor...